# PCA variance is sum of eigenvalues?

Tags: pca

Earlier today in a lecture we were shown some slides that showed that the variance of k is equal to the sum of the first k eigenvalues.

There was a bit where I got totally lost

[image]

Can someone explain what's happening here? How do we get from the LHS to the RHS? I've searched online but haven't been able to find anything relevant.

Update: This is the entire slide:

[image]

Comment: What are $m$, $k$, $u_j$ and $x^{(i)}$?

Comment: I would feel dishonest if I did not mention: if this is in the context of regression, using the percentage of variance retained to determine which principal components to use in a regression is often given, but quite poor, advice.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the variables have been centered already, which explains the second-to-last equality in the slide.
$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (u_j^\top x^{(i)})^2
= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m u_j^\top x^{(i)} (x^{(i)})^\top u_j
= u_j^\top \left(\frac{1}{m} X^\top X\right) u_j
= \lambda_j,$$
since $u_j$ was presumably defined to be a unit eigenvector of $\frac{1}{m} X^\top X$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.